# How can I find what UserAgent gets attached to my URL requests?

Tags: http-functions

The documentation for [`HTTPRequest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HTTPRequest.html) notes that it is possible to indicate a user agent, and that

> The default "UserAgent" is typically "Wolfram HTTPClient xxxx", where xxxx is a version number.

How can I find out what this version number is? Ideally this should be done locally and without outgoing network traffic.

I ask because I am writing code to probe an API and I would like to override the default UserAgent in a way that identifies the queries as coming from the package and giving a contact address, but without destroying existing information that could be useful in diagnosing any problems in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HTTPRequest[""]["Headers"]
```

> {"user-agent" -> "Wolfram HTTPClient 12.3"}

or

```
HTTPRequest["www.wolfram.com"] // ExportString[#, "HTTPRequest"] &
```

> ```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> host: www.wolfram.com
> user-agent: Wolfram HTTPClient 12.3
> ```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine and should be the accepted one :)

Comment: @CarlLange who knows what is fed to the underling curl library functions, your answer shows the truth :)

Comment: @Kuba True, but ultimately we have to take Mathematica at its word. If there's a difference between the user agent reported internally in this way and what's actually sent out, what's to stop Mathematica from messing with an intentionally set user agent?

Answer (score 6):

If you have the ability to `CloudDeploy` functions, you can do it like so:

```
obj = CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{}, $UserAgentString &], 
  Permissions -> "Public"]

Import[First[obj]]
```

> `"Wolfram HTTPClient 12.2"`

Make sure to clean up after yourself:

```
DeleteObject[obj]
```

What we are doing here is deploying an API endpoint that simply returns the User Agent string in the response body, then querying that API and outputting the body (by `Import`ing the `First` part of `obj`, which is the URL of our API).

In any case, the expectation would be that the version in the user agent is going to be the version of the Wolfram Language you use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The `CloudDeploy` solution doesn't really work for me (this is for a package and I would like this to run on user machines seamlessly) but that last paragraph is probably enough for my needs.

Comment: I also tried to do this with GenerateHTTPRequest but it doesn't seem to actually _do_ a HTTP request, so the CloudDeploy option was the easiest I could come up with. I'm glad it helps anyways :)